# Excel Date Formula + 3 Months

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

I am looking to have a formula that takes the date that is manually input in a cell (E2) and automatically populates a date in the column next to it (F2) that is + 3 months from the date manually input in (E2).

eg. If (E2) has 03/11/2021 input manually then the formula in (F2) would populate 03/02/2021. [image of part of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlSPB.png)

Comment: FYI: Your example is wrong. You can simply do `= E2 + 90` if you define a month as 30 day window. If you just want to add 3 to the month value and leave the day value as is, the solution below works just fine :)

Comment: You are right, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Right so the very simple fix of = E2 + 90 is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+X,DAY(A1))
```

where X = 3

Comment: Just a word of warning.  This can get funky at the ends of the months.  For example in A1 put the 30th of November and add 3 months.  It will return the 2nd of March in the following year.  That may be what the OP wants it may not.

Answer (score 3):

One can use [EDATE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5):

```
=EDATE(A1,3)
```

The second criteria is the number of Months to add.

EDATE will go to the number of months then try to equate the day.  If the day exceeds the number of days in the target month it returns the last day of the target month.

For example `=EDATE(DATE(2021,11,30),3)` will return the 28th of February 2021.